# In python, how to reshape a dataframe so that some datetime columns become rows

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pivot-table

In a pandas dataframe, I want to transpose and agrupate datetime columns into rows.

Like this (there are about 12 date columns):

```
 Category   Type    11/2021 12/2021
0   A        1       0.0     20
1   A        2       NaN     13
2   B        1       5.0      7
3   B        2       20.0     4
```

to one like this:

```
    Date    Category    Type1   Type2
0   2021-11    A         0       NaN
1   2021-11    B         5       20.0
2   2021-12    A         20      13.0
3   2021-12    B         7       4.0
```

I tought about using pivot tables, but I wasnt able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
(df.melt(['Category', 'Type'], var_name = 'Date').
   pivot(['Date', 'Category'],'Type').reset_index())

         Date Category value      
Type                       1     2
0     11/2021        A   0.0   NaN
1     11/2021        B   5.0  20.0
2     12/2021        A  20.0  13.0
3     12/2021        B   7.0   4.0
```

To be alitle cleaner you could use `janitor`:

```
import janitor

(df.pivot_longer(['Category', 'Type'], names_to = 'Date', values_to = 'type').
  pivot_wider(['Date', 'Category'], names_from = 'Type', names_sep = ''))

      Date Category   type1   type2
0  11/2021        A     0.0     NaN
1  11/2021        B     5.0    20.0
2  12/2021        A    20.0    13.0
3  12/2021        B     7.0     4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
x = (
    df.set_index(["Category", "Type"])
    .stack()
    .unstack("Type")
    .add_prefix("Type")
    .reset_index()
)
x = x.rename(columns={"level_1": "Date"})
x.columns.name = None

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  Category     Date  Type1  Type2
0        A  11/2021    0.0    NaN
1        A  12/2021   20.0   13.0
2        B  11/2021    5.0   20.0
3        B  12/2021    7.0    4.0
```